# Is there any way to initialize settings model of c# on startup from the JSON settings available in the database in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.0

I have created a web application in which I am using .net core 3.0 as server-side technology and have Postgres as backend. I have a table called settings in the database in which I am storing settings as JSON using JSON data type available in Postgres.

Now I want to initialize my settings model in the application from the JSON data available in the database. I want to initialize the model at the start of the application and use it throughout the application wherever needed to avoid the database roundtrips for fetching the settings from the database on demand.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Following is the Json data in the database:

```
{
    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
    "CurrencySymbol": "$"
}
```

Here is my C# model in the application

```
public class SettingsModel
{
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }

    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking to achieve this in the following way but still does not have idea about what and how to use it.

Initializing the model using singleton service

```
services.AddSingleton<SettingsModel, GetJsonSettingsFromDatabase()>();
```

GetJsonSettingsFromDatabase() will return the SettingsModel after deserializing the settings from DB to SettingsModel .

I also wanted some function that will contain the logic for updating the SettingsModel so that I can invoke the same when there are changes in the database table for settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing the model using singleton service should use the factory delegate

For example.

```
services.AddSingleton<SettingsModel>(sp => return GetJsonSettingsFromDatabase());
```

assuming

> `GetJsonSettingsFromDatabase()` will return the `SettingsModel` after deserializing the settings from DB to `SettingsModel`.

The same could have been done with an instance

```
SettingsModel settings = GetJsonSettingsFromDatabase();
services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

As for

> I also wanted some function that will contain the logic for updating the SettingsModel so that I can invoke the same when there are changes in the database table for settings.

Then do not register it as a singleton. Consider caching the settings instance to avoid round trips and only loading fresh instance as needed.

Comment: Ok, got your point. Then which caching mechanism should I use to cache the entire model or shall I cache the JSON data only?